# Incoming webhook request size limits

Tags: microsoft-teams

What is the size limit for requests sent to incoming webhooks?

I tried looking for this information in the documentation but could not find it.

I like to send MessageCard to the incoming webhooks. The MessageCard will have an image but I don't want to use an URL for the image but instead want to embed the image. This works on Card Playground (https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) but I'm getting a HTTP 413 error when sending to incoming webhook.

I don't want to persist the image to file if I don't have to.

Comment: Incoming Webhook message limit is 28K.

Comment: Could you please try with smaller image and let me know still you are facing any issues?

Comment: I ended up persisting the image to file but it is good to know about the message limit.

BTW - Just curious, when will AdaptiveCard be supported with incoming webhooks?

Comment: Currently adaptive cards are not supporting with incoming web hooks. We don't have any time lines to share for now.

Comment: I'm just wondering where can one find that stated 28K limit?

Comment: This page says "Approximately 28 KB per post" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams although it doesn't seem to be specifically talking about webhooks