# How long can messages be when posting to a Microsoft Teams connector webhook?

Tags: json, limit, webhooks, microsoft-teams, payload

I am posting the results/logs of a CI/CD system to Microsoft Teams. While handling some failed builds with longer results, I stumbled upon the following error returned by the webhook URL `https://outlook.office.com/webhook/bb6bfee7-1820-49fd-b9f9-f28f7cc679ff@<uuid1>/IncomingWebhook/<id>/<uuid2>`:

```
Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 413 with ContextId tcid=3626521845697697778,server=DB3PEPF0000009A,cv=BmkbJ1NdTkv1EDoqr7n/rg.0..
```

As I observe, this is caused by too long payload posted to the Teams webhook URL.

The initial complex message (sections, titles, subtitles, formatted links, `<pre>` formatted text, etc.) was failing when the JSON payload was a above 18000 characters.

Testing a bit with the payload I observed that the more formatting I remove from the raw JSON payload, the longer can the Teams message be. The longest message I could post had (according cu cURL): `Content-Length: 20711`. The JSON payload for this message was:

```
{"themeColor":"ED4B35","text":"a....a"}
```

whitespaces in the JSON format seem not to count (i.e. adding spaces will not decrease the maximum message length that I can sent to the Teams webhook).

For reference, the initial message was looking similar to this:

```
{
    "themeColor": "ED4B35",
    "summary": "iris-shared-libs - shared-library-updates - failure",
    "sections": [
        {
            "activityTitle": "Job: [iris-shared-libs](https://my.concourse.net/teams/hsm/pipelines/iris-shared-libs) - [shared-library-updates #89](https://my.concourse.sccloudinfra.net/teams/hsm/pipelines/iris-shared-libs/jobs/shared-library-updates/builds/89) (FAILURE)",
            "activityImage": "https://via.placeholder.com/200.png/ED4B35/FFFFFF?text=F",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Failed step",
                    "value": "update-shared-libraries"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "text": "Trying a new strategy with gated versioned releases",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "name": "Repository",
                    "value": "[iris-concourse-resources](https://my.git.com/projects/IRIS/repos/iris-concourse-resources)"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Commit",
                    "value": "[2272145ddf9285c9933df398d63cbe680a62f2b7](https://my.git.com/projects/IRIS/repos/iris-concourse-resources/commits/2272145ddf9285c9933df398d63cbe680a62f2b7)"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Author",
                    "value": "me@company.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "activityTitle": "Job failed step logs part 1",
            "text": "<pre>...very long log text goes here ...</pre>"
        }
    ]
}
```

What is the actual maximum lengths of the Microsoft Teams connector webhook posted message?

The [official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/limits-specifications-teams) does not mention it. In the Feedback section at the bottom there is still an open question regarding "Messages size limits?" with the feedback: "We are currently investigating this."

Comment: One of the key observation here is that Webhook end point returns status code 200 and these error message are part of the response body . Even in case of rate limit as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) in the Rate limit section there is code snippet which says we need to check the content body

Comment: Perhaps this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957658/incoming-webhook-request-size-limits

Answer (score 6):

From the tests I made so far, some limits observed (if this is independent of the server) are roughly, based on the JSON message payload (structure and formatting) **between 18000 and 40000** (with length below 18000 never breaking and above 40000 always breaking).

- Use case 18000: one long text for a section
- Use case 40000: 600 facts with very short name and empty string as value

And removing a fragment of the JSON payload and adding an equal number of characters in another JSON value will not give you the same maximum.

I have observed a soft limit (message truncated, but no error) as well on the maximum number of sections: **10**. The sections starting with the 11th are discarded.

Comment: In case of android mobile app, we can see more than 10 sections message without truncation. Truncation we have seen on the desktop app